# Fonts have different physical sizes on different displays even when sizes are setted in SP

Tags: android, android-styles, android-fonts

I'm testing my app on two devices. The first is HTC One S which have 540x960 4.3 inches display and 256ppi. Second is Sony Miro - 320x480, 165ppi, 3.5 inches.

In My app I set font sizes with "sp" units, which should provide density-independence and make fonts looks same on any display:

```
 <style name = "WhiteTextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

But what I actually got is that fonts on the Sony phone is bigger that on the HTC one.

How to make them look the same? Or I just not getting how that should work?
I compared font sizes on these two devices in other apps and on both devices fonts have same physical sizes.

Comment: Use different `dimens.xml` files in your `values` folders for different screen densities and resolutions.

Comment: SP, DP are approximations. They won't be spot on. SP also varies with device configuration (e.g. Settings -> Display -> Font Size -> Big )

Comment: I use it for now, but is it proper solution? Is the use of "sp" units should not provide what I need?